# Ifelse with 3 conditions and 2 outcomes

Tags: r

I want to replace the values of var2 subject to conditions as follows:

1. if var1 is not equal to 1 or 2, then var2 equals its original value
2. if var1 equals 1 or 2, and var3 equals 1, then var2 equals its original value.  Otherwise var2 equals 1

I have this:

[image]

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .35 | 1 |
| 2 | .42 | .11 |
| 3 | .51 | .21 |
| 4 | .39 | 1 |

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .35 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | .11 |
| 3 | .51 | .21 |
| 4 | .39 | 1 |

This is my code, but it is not producing the desired output.

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c(1, 2, 3, 4), var2=c(.35, .42, .51, .39),
             var3=c(1, .11, .21, 1))

df2 <- df %>% mutate(var2 = ifelse(var1 != 1 | var1 != 2, var2, 
                          ifelse(var1 == 1 | var1 == 2 & var3 == 1, var2, 1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just needed change in `&` and `|`

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(var2 = ifelse(var1 != 1 & var1 != 2, var2, 
                                   ifelse(var1 == 1 & var1 == 2 | var3 == 1, var2, 1)))

  var1 var2 var3
1    1 0.35 1.00
2    2 1.00 0.11
3    3 0.51 0.21
4    4 0.39 1.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the condition showed in OP's post, use `case_when`.  Also, for multiple elements, instead of `==`, use `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(var2 = case_when(
    # if var1 is not equal to 1 or 2, 
    #then var2 equals its original value
     !var1  %in% 1:2 ~ var2,
    # var1 equals 1 or 2, and var3 equals 1, 
    #then var2 equals its original value
   var1 %in% 1:2 & var3 == 1 ~ var2, 
   # otherwise equals 1
   TRUE ~ 1))
```

-output

```
  var1 var2 var3
1    1 0.35 1.00
2    2 1.00 0.11
3    3 0.51 0.21
4    4 0.39 1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter version of `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(var2 = ifelse(var1 > 2 | var3 == 1, var2, 1)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

```
   var1  var2  var3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  0.35  1   
2     2  1     0.11
3     3  0.51  0.21
4     4  0.39  1
```